# CICD for Drupal website

Tags: jenkins, drupal

I have ansible scripts which will install the Drupal. On the other hand, I have a website for which the database is pushed onto bitbucket. How can I perform CICD with these? My automation scripts will setup Drupal. How can I get the wesbite database on the newly installed plain Drupal?

I'm using ansible playbook via jenkins to install Drupal on some node (Linux machine). Once the Drupal is installed, I would like to get my website too.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to integrate [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) for CI/CD as it has the industry leading position in the sector. [Pantheon](https://pantheon.io/docs/guides/build-tools/) recommends using GitHub, CircleCI, & Composer for CI/CD but you can easily substitute BitBucket in the workflow.